# VTK rendering with wsl

Tags: c++, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vtk

I use WSL and tried to render a simple image with VTK. I used the following c++ code:

```
#include <vtkVersion.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkImageData.h>
#include <vtkDataSetMapper.h>
#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>

int main(int, char*[])
{
  // Create an image data
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> imageData = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData>::New();
  
  // Specify the size of the image data
  imageData->SetDimensions(3,3,2);
  imageData->SetSpacing(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  imageData->SetOrigin(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataSetMapper> mapper = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataSetMapper>::New();
#if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
  mapper->SetInputConnection(imageData->GetProducerPort());
#else
  mapper->SetInputData(imageData);
#endif
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
  actor->SetMapper(mapper);
  
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
  
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
  
  // Add both renderers to the window
  renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
      
  // Add a sphere to the left and a cube to the right
  renderer->AddActor(actor);
  
  renderer->ResetCamera();
  
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
  renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);
  //renderWindow->Render();
  renderWindowInteractor->Start();
  
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and used CMake with the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(test)

find_package(VTK)
message (STATUS "VTK_VERSION: ${VTK_VERSION}")
  add_executable(test test.cxx )
  target_link_libraries(test ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
  vtk_module_autoinit(
    TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    MODULES ${VTK_LIBRARIES}
  )
```

I can compile and run it but I just get a window but it's black. It is by the way a simple example of VTK. I use VcXsrv and disabled native OpenGL. I also set `export GL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=0` and when I run `glxgears` they are rotating.

I always get the following printed to my console:

```
[               80D00780]vtkOpenGLFramebufferObj:1390  WARN| failed at glBlitFramebuffer 1 OpenGL errors detected
  0 : (1282) Invalid operation
```

Thank you for your help!